# Tablas eolicas en python

Tags: python-3.x

estoy usando una tabla de excel y la estoy abriendo en python, como hago para insertar en la ultima columna de todas las filas, quiero insertar el texto Estacion1 en una columna nueva y que todas las filas digan Estacion1 tambien.

Por ahora tengo este codigo y he podido insertar ese valor pero me aparece en la mitad, quiero agregarla al final

```
Tabla = open('Estacion1.csv', 'r').readlines()
x = list(Tabla)
x = [z.replace('\n', ', Estacion1') for z in x]``
x = [z.split(';') for z in x]
x[1:] = [z + [z[0].split('/')[1]] for z in x[1:]]
x[0].append('Mes')
x[1:] = [z + [z[0].split('/')[2]] for z in x[1:]]
x[0].append('Año')
x[1:] = [z + [z[0].split('/')[0]] for z in x[1:]]
x[0].append('Dia')
x[1:] = [z + [z[1].split(':')[0]] for z in x[1:]]
x[0].append('Hora')
x
```

este es output

```
[['FECHA', 'HHMMSS', 'DIR', 'VEL, Estacion1', 'Mes', 'Año', 'Dia', 'Hora'],
 ['16/04/05', '11:10:00', '135', '6,3, Estacion1', '04', '05', '16', '11'],
 ['16/04/05', '11:20:00', '135', '5,1, Estacion1', '04', '05', '16', '11'],
 ['16/04/05', '11:30:00', '135', '6,3, Estacion1', '04', '05', '16', '11'],
 ['16/04/05', '11:40:00', '113', '6,1, Estacion1', '04', '05', '16', '11'],
```

Quiero que la columna Estacion1 quede al final

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de “estacion1.csv”, del resultado que obtienes y del resultado que esperas obtener, porque tienes un código bastante funky de entender. De primeras te aconsejaría que usaras `Pandas` antes que los built-ins para casi cualquier cosa que tenga que ver con la manipulación de tablas de datos.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren muchas maneras de arreglar eso, pero te sugiero dos:

## 1.EXCEL

Si dices que viene la tabla desde Excel, ¿por qué no cortas y pegas la columna antes de pasarla al programa? Es bastante fácil y cómodo y te ahorras complicar tu código

## 2.PANDAS

Si aun así quiere limpiar la tabla desde Python usa `Pandas` mejor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', delimiter=';')  # Asumo que usas ';' como separador, sino cambialo al que utilice tu archivo
df.drop('Estacion1', axis=1, inplace=True)  # Esto borra la columna entera (axis=1) llamada 'Estacion1' en la misma linea de codigo (inplace=True)
df['Estacion'] = 'Estacion 1'  # Esto te crea una columna entera llamada 'Estacion' con el valor 'Estacion 1' por defecto
```

A partir de aquí `df` se convierte en un objeto de Pandas con el que puedes trabajar más cómodamente, ordenar por columnas, filtrar, etc.

Si quieres volver a convertir a csv...

```
df.to_csv('datos_limpios.csv')
```

Y te crea un archivo con el contenido del objeto `df`

Puedes exportar no solo a csv, también a excel, a texto...incluso a sqlite!

Para añadir columnas simplemente tienes que tratarlas como si ya existieran, por eso...

```
df['Estacion'] = 'Estacion 1'
```

...funciona como por arte de magia.

Si te sientes más cómodo trabajando con lista de listas (las filas de la tabla) también puedes hacerlo:

```
lista = df.values.tolist()
```

Hay mucha documentación muy buena sobre `Pandas` y guías en YouTube muy útiles, te animo a que eches un vistazo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, como dices tu funciona por arte de magia.

Comment: Bueno, aunque cuando fui a probar el lista = df.values.tolist()  me salio este mensaje:                                                                                                         IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: Eso es porque si tú dataframe es muy grande y el notebook quizás intente mostrar el output completo. Pruébalo en consola